# Ember Data grab already loaded objects from store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember 1.13.6 and Ember Data 1.13.7, I am wondering how I can get the already loaded objects from the store without doing a call to the server (where relationship is async).

Image following model:

```
//page model
export default DS.Model.extend({
    parent: DS.belongsTo('page', { async: false, inverse: 'subpages'}),
    subpages: DS.hasMany('page',{ async: true, inverse: 'parent' }),
 });
```

If you just call `model.get('subpages')`, Ember Data returns a promise + make a call to the server. Normally this is fine behaviour, but now I got a special case I just want to grab the already loaded objects.

I can't find anything about such case in the docs. The only way I found at the moment is by using private properties:

```
model._internalModel._relationships.initializedRelationships.subpages.canonicalState
```

Of course I seek a normal way to achieve this, without touching the inner code of Ember Data. So does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it from relationships directly, but you can peek.

```
this.store.peekAll('page')
```

Wouldn't call the backend. You could probably use a filter, they don't hit the backend:

```
existingSubpages: function(){
  return this.store.filter('page', item => {
    return item.parent === this;
  });
}.property('subpages.@each')
```

Comment: Yeah, was already afraid that's the case. Pity a `peekQuery` does not exist  though (or even beter, something like `model.get('subpages', false)`, so you could force the get the object without doing a call).

Comment: @JacobvanLingen After a bit of thought I think a filter might be a nicer choice. You could add `existingSubpages` to the model. (I didn't set up a test environment for it, you may have to fidget a bit).

Comment: Cool, didn't even think I could use the store inside my model too! Awesome man :)

Comment: FWIW, since Ember Data 1.13.8 one can filter directly from peekAll `this.store.peekAll('page').filterBy(...);`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Kit Sunde's answer, there maybe a situation where you want some objects to have an async relation and other objects to have a sync relation.

With the ready hook this can easily be implemented:

```
 ready() {
    if(this.get('relationIsSynced')) { //whater case you got
        this.set('subpages.content.relationship.isAsync', false);
    }
 }
```